# C++ How to pass a parameter to an STL function

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

I had to pass an unordered map to the comparator function of a priority queue and using the link [Passing a parameter to a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066576/passing-a-parameter-to-a-comparison-function) I decided to do it as follows:

```
 priority_queue < int, std::vector<int>, compare(freq) > pq;
 struct compare
    {
        compare( std::unordered_map<int,int>& freq1 )
        {
            freq = freq1;
        }

        bool operator()( int& el1, int& el2 ){
            return freq[el1] < freq[el2];
        }    
        std::unordered_map<int,int> freq;
    };
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
Template argument for template type parameter must be a type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create my own comparator for a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/how-can-i-create-my-own-comparator-for-a-map) - it's the same for an `unordered_map`

Comment: @churill: not sure if I understand. Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message said, `compare(freq)` is not a type, it can't be specified as the type template argument.

You should specify `compare(freq)` as the argument of the [constructor of `priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), and specify `compare` as the type template argument.

```
priority_queue < int, std::vector<int>, compare> pq{compare(freq)};
//                                      ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```